# R S3 handle two double qoute with fread

Tags: r, amazon-s3, datatable, fread

I want to read in a pretty large csv file from S3 including entries like `Hawaii 21"" pizza`. However, I noticed that if I use `fread` (which I do prefer as it's faster), entries include two double quotes changes into `Hawaii 21"""" pizza`. This kind of issue does not occur if I use `read.csv`.

I noticed the warning message recommends to add `quote=""` in order to avoid the issue. But how can I insert it in `s3_read_using` function?

I can use `gsub` to make extra quotes disappear, but still wondering if there's any direct solution to it.

And below is my read-in code:

`table <- s3read_using(FUN=fread, object='mytable.csv', bucket="mybucket/tables")
 table <- s3read_using(FUN=read.csv, object='mytable.csv', bucket="mybucket/tables")`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
table <- s3read_using(FUN=fread, quote="\"", object='mytable.csv', bucket="mybucket/tables")
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but isn't `quote="\""` default for fread?

Comment: You can pass arguments to `s3read_using` like that which will be used by fread.